# Can't boot system from USB bootable drive

Tags: windows, boot, windows-10, usb, reboot

Is there any way to check from the command prompt the boot order, because when I start my computer up, I have no idea what key I have to press, I tried f10, f12, f8, and pressing like most of the f keys really quickly as if to somehow "catch" the one I am supposed to on start up. I am using windows 10. I have my bootable usb drive inside. I just want to boot my system from it. Help?

Comment: Make and Model of PC???

Comment: MS industrial... Not sure about this. Can I check somewhere to know for sure? In windows interface i mean?

Comment: Try tapping ESC rapidly after turning on the power, or hold down the space bar constantly from power on (often causes keyboard error and a prompt)

Comment: Found it: Make: MSI Model : MS-7636

Comment: According to a random webpage (http://smallbusiness.chron.com/bios-msi-motherboard-54604.html) it's probably DEL or F2

Comment: Also try TAB in case it's made by AMI.

Comment: MSI motherboards use the Delete key to enter the bios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

okay, you cannot change the boot order from within windows because the boot order is in the BIOS. once you boot up an OS, you cannot boot another one at the same time, so you will need to boot your usb first. enter the BIOS and change the boot order that way. it depends on your computer, specifically your motherboard. look online to see how you access the BIOS on your motherboard. for most brands, it usually either tapping esc or f1 or f2 or f10 rapidly. if you are on a laptop, also try to look online to see how to access the BIOS of that line of laptop of that gen of that company/brand. once you are in the BIOS, look around to find the boot order. you can look this up online as well. don't change anything that you don't know. normally, there will be a 'do you want to save' message popping up when you leave a part of the BIOS or leave the BIOS. only press save when you are certain. press no to not save or cancel to return to BIOS do sth else you forgot. in the event you press save and mess up, you can always go back into the BIOS and reset to default. you can help me and others here by telling us the model of your motherboard or your laptop.